# Should numerology be considered on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Numerology is any belief in divine, mystical or other special relationship between a number and some coinciding events. It has many systems and traditions and beliefs.

Wikipedia does not define specifically Hindu numerology, but still we know that it is a widely accepted practice in India and hence we must define whether it is off-topic or on-topic.

There are some authors which have written about [Indian Numerology](http://www.sanatansociety.org/vedic_astrology_and_numerology/indian_numerology.htm#.U6vDJkBqPyU) and it is widely used in India with regard to buying items, registering cars/houses etc. This may not necessarily mean that it is a part of Hinduism though.

Nonetheless, is it off-topic or on-topic?

Comment: I don't know enough about Hindu numerology to say for sure, but I think that this seems like it would make sense being on-topic. Here's the big issue - these questions are bound to attract crackpots who posit _their own_ numerological theories rather than citing the theories of actual scholars. I think we need to do a sort of cost-benefit analysis here - do we get enough benefit out of allowing numerology questions to offset the cost of dealing with crackpots?

Comment: @senshin We will end up having questions like is No. 9 lucky for me? I think these should be restricted to **factual, non-personal** questions. But numerology in general if you consider is opinion based, so I would be in favor of deeming it off-topic in general as well.

Comment: Bhrigu-samhita described all three: astrology, numerology and palmistry, but it is considered to be largely lost. The topic itself would be great, but how will we get good answers?

Answer (score 1):

If any logy is conduced by or written in volumes by Rishis or traditions, which goes back to devatas, then the logy should be accepted here.

Numerology has no tradition in India unlike Jyotish. Jyotish includes Samhita, Ganita & Hora. Numerology doesn't belong to any of the sub branch.